# xcode-select error malformed developer path

Tags: xcode, d, dmd, xcrun

I'm trying to compile a program in D on a 2011 Macbook Air using DMD and I am getting this strange error at the command line.

```
xcode-select: error: malformed developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools")
--- errorlevel 1
```

Before this error, I was getting:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
--- errorlevel 1
```

So I just copied xcrun from /usr/bin/ to the path shown above, and that's when I started getting the top error.

I installed DMD through the disk image. I have tried re-installing DMD through brew with no luck.

I can't find any information about this error elsewhere. Help!

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? Xcode should install additional command line tools.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with DMD. Can you compile the program on the CLI with dmd? e.g. `dmd *.d` ?

Answer (score 2):

So Lander was correct in his comment. I simply did not have the Xcode tools installed. To be fair, nothing in the DMD installation documentation said that I would need Xcode for this.